# Categorize a numerical variable into 20 bins (R)

Tags: r

I have some issues when I try to convert my numerical variable into a categorical one. I want to have my column "Price" divided into 20 bins (in order to do a classification tree then).

I tried with the function cut, and it worked, but my intervals are expressed in scientific notation ...

Here is a sample of my data:

```
Mydata <- data.frame(
Price = c(13500,13750,13950,14950,13750,12950)
)
```

Here is my code :

```
Mydata[,2] = cut(Mydata$Price, 3, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

Then, my 2nd colonne have numbers like (3.11e+04,3.25e+04] for example.
I also do with the argument labels = FALSE, but this is not what I'm looking for (then, the bins are expressed in numbers -> 1,2,3, ...,20. I want them to be expressed in intervals -> [0;1000], [1000, 2000], etc...)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You should provide reproducible example data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: If your goal is a classification try, why not let the tree fitting algorithm determine optimal cutpoints by giving it a numeric variable?

Comment: Sorry - I've edited my question.
This is for an exercise at school, and they ask us to create a new variable that categorizes the price into 20 bins ... I'm not sure that the tree fitting code in R can divide my data into 20 bins, as the algorithm stops at some point

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution ! With dig.lab

```
Mydata <- data.frame(
Price = c(13500,13750,13950,14950,13750,12950)
)
```

Here is my code :

```
Mydata[,2] = cut(Mydata$Price, 3, include.lowest=TRUE, dig.lab = 5)
```

Thanks anyway for your tips :)

Answer (score 0):

If your object `Mydata` has class `matrix`, then I have a clue to what may be going on:

The `cut()` function returns a factor that looks like this:

```
> x <- runif(10, 0, 2)
> cut(x, 2)
 [1] (1.01,1.95]  (1.01,1.95]  (0.069,1.01] (1.01,1.95]  (1.01,1.95]  
 (1.01,1.95]  (1.01,1.95]  (1.01,1.95]  (1.01,1.95] 
 [10] (1.01,1.95] 
 Levels: (0.069,1.01] (1.01,1.95]
```

The `cut()` function is naturally returning a set of intervals (as you requested). The output is a *factor*. **This is important.** Now watch what happens when I force the output to be numeric:

```
> as.numeric(cut(x, 2))
[1] 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
```

That's a numeric vector. Why does this matter? Because objects of class `matrix` in `R` can only have one type. Any new values added to a matrix will be *coerced* to the type of the rest of the entries in the matrix. Watch:

```
> X_mat <- matrix(1:10L, nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
> X_mat[, 2] <- cut(x, 2)
> X_mat
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1    2
 [2,]    2    2
 [3,]    3    1
 [4,]    4    2
 [5,]    5    2
 [6,]    6    2
 [7,]    7    2
 [8,]    8    2
 [9,]    9    2
[10,]   10    2
```

The intervals returned by the `cut()` function are gone, because they were transformed to class `numeric` to match the rest of the matrix `X_mat`. What if we use a data frame instead?

```
> X_df <- data.frame(x1 = 1:10L)
> X_df[, 2] <- cut(x, 2)
> X_df
  x1           V2
1   1  (1.01,1.95]
2   2  (1.01,1.95]
3   3 (0.069,1.01]
4   4  (1.01,1.95]
5   5  (1.01,1.95]
6   6  (1.01,1.95]
7   7  (1.01,1.95]
8   8  (1.01,1.95]
9   9  (1.01,1.95]
10 10  (1.01,1.95]
```

Basically, if you want to preserve the *structure* of the output from `cut()`, your data needs to be in a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I've just edited my question to give a sample of my data as an example, and it is a data.frame